# I can not update angular cli to the lastest version globally

Tags: angular-cli

I can not update angular cli to the lastest version globally

I tried this

```
npm uninstall -g @angular-cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

but my angular version is:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.15
Node: 12.22.1
OS: linux x64

Angular: 9.1.13
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes
```

Comment: Are you running ng command inside any angular application which has v9?

Comment: no I am runing in other terminal

Comment: Did you find a solution ? Same problem here